# Monitoring lists using LiveBindings

Tags: delphi, list, delphi-xe2, livebindings

I've been trying to find a *generic* way to notify a UI control of changes in a list. For example, when an object is added to a list I want it added automatically to the listbox. If an object is removed from the list, I want it removed automatically from the listbox.

Unfortunately there are some maddening inconsistencies between Delphi's lists: TList<>.Notify is fine but TStringList.OnChange doesn't even tell you what the change was and TList doesn't even have any notification whatsoever!

I was hoping LiveBindings would give me a proper way of monitoring changes in most lists, but so far I don't see it. All the examples I have seen fills the control and sets up bindings between the list items and the control items (listbox items in my example). But adding/removing an object from the list doesn't affect the control at all.

Does anyone know of a mechanism that I have missed, or more generally, a nice generic way to do this?

**Clarification:**
It doesn't seem that I was clear enough before. The reason I need a generic way, is because I wrote a grid control that can connect to a variety of sources, including some existing code. I wrote an interface that the grid accepts as source and then a number of adapter classes to accept some lists and make them available as that interface. Since I needed to accept existing code as well, overriding TList.Notify is not an option. And since there is no event to see the changes, it effectively means TList does not have a notification mechanism that is usable by a client, such as my adapter class. TStrings doesn't have one either, but TStringList raises a simple OnChange, which means that the adapter class cannot actually determine what has changed.

I actually had a very nice solution that used the [TVirtualMethodInterceptor](http://blog.barrkel.com/2010/09/virtual-method-interception.html), but that completely stopped working in Delphi XE and its not fixed in XE2.

Comment: TList has notifications, but you have to override the protected `Notify` method.

Comment: @The_Fox This is the answer, at least for TList. You should write it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the `TList.Notify` mechanism.

`TList` has a protected `Notify` procedure that you must override. This is the way TObjectList works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, The_Fox, but my problem is that I don't control the code containing the list. Consequently I cannot override a virtual method to do what I want and the default TList.Notify does nothing. I need code external to the list to be able to monitor changes, which is why I hoped LiveBindings may provide a usable mechanism. I updated the description to accurately reflect my use case and why overriding a virtual won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late answer, but the generic TList has an OnNotify including the item added or removed.